# Can not update Azure Application Gateway - Error: The disabled Rule '920300' is unknown

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

Every time we try to make any update to a particular instance of application gateway we get the error.

> Failed to save configuration changes to application gateway
>   '********'. Error: The disabled Rule '920300' is unknown for RuleGroup
>   'REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT' for Application Gateway Firewall in
>   context
>   'properties.webApplicationFirewallConfiguration.disabledRuleGroups[0]'.

This error occurs both from the portal and when using powershell and occurs when trying to make any change to the app gateway config e.g. edit a rule, add a listener, edit the WAF settings.

Rule **920300 Request Missing an Accept Header** was previously listed in the WAF settings but I note it is no longer listed in the portal

[portal appgw settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6THE9.png)

but is listed in the docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-crs-rulegroups-rules#owasp30

Answer (score 1):

This is the Ruleset definition:

```
# -=[ Rule Logic ]=-
```

## This rule generates a notice if the Accept header is missing.

SecRule &REQUEST_HEADERS:Accept "@eq 0" \
    "msg:'Request Missing an Accept Header',\
    chain,\
    phase:request,\
    rev:'3',\
    ver:'OWASP_CRS/3.0.0',\
    maturity:'9',\
    accuracy:'8',\
    t:none,\
    **pass,**
    severity:'NOTICE',\
    id:920300,\
    tag:'application-multi',\
    tag:'language-multi',\
    tag:'platform-multi',\
    tag:'attack-protocol',\
    tag:'OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/MISSING_HEADER_ACCEPT',\
    tag:'WASCTC/WASC-21',\
    tag:'OWASP_TOP_10/A7',\
    tag:'PCI/6.5.10',\
    tag:'paranoia-level/2'"
    SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "!^OPTIONS$" \
        "chain"
        SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent "!@pm AppleWebKit Android" \
            "t:none,\
            setvar:'tx.msg=%{rule.msg}',\
            setvar:tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.notice_anomaly_score},\
            setvar:tx.%{rule.id}-OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/MISSING_HEADER-%{matched_var_name}=%{matched_var}"

It is just a warning and it will not block your traffic. You are just seeing an warning here in your WAF logs and it can be ignored.